# 'Response headers must contain header', u'location'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I try to upload a video in a Google Cloud Storage bucket by using resumable upload.
But I always have the same error : (u'Response headers must contain header', u'location')

Here is my code:

```
client = _get_storage_client()
bucket = client.bucket(BUCKET_NAME, PROJECT_ID)
blob = bucket.blob(filename)

if 'video' in content_type:
    url = blob.create_resumable_upload_session(content_type=content_type, client=client)
    stream = io.BytesIO(stream_file.file.read())


    upload = ResumableUpload(
            upload_url=url,
            chunk_size=chunk_size
        )
    transport = AuthorizedSession(credentials=client._credentials)

    # Start using the Resumable Upload
    response = upload.initiate(
            transport=transport,
            content_type=content_type,
            stream=stream,
            metadata={'name': blob.name}
        )
    while upload.finished is False:
        upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)
```

The error appear at the upload.initiate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem maybe are in

```
url = blob.create_resumable_upload_session(content_type=content_type, 
client=client)
```

check the post [here](https://dev.to/sethmichaellarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h), they use

```
# Create a Resumable Upload
url = (
  f'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'
  f'{bucket.name}/o?uploadType=resumable'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most probably has to with authorization. The problem here is that the line

```
response = upload.initiate(
            transport=transport,
            content_type=content_type,
            stream=stream,
            metadata={'name': blob.name}
        )
```

does not contain the google cloud response. 
I would advise you to debug this statement if you step into this statement you will find

```
        method, url, payload, headers = self._prepare_initiate_request(
            stream, metadata, content_type,
            total_bytes=total_bytes, stream_final=stream_final)
        result = _helpers.http_request(
            transport, method, url, data=payload, headers=headers,
            retry_strategy=self._retry_strategy)
        self._process_initiate_response(result)
        return result
```

If you inspect the 'result' variable. It will provide you with the HTTP status code (403 for non authorized). The content of the result will provide you with the reason and the access right that is required.

Another possibility is to send your request through a proxy and inspect the HTTP result.